# Position cursor when asking a user for input in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a custom function in Vim which asks the user what they would like to rename the current file to:

```
let b:newname = input('Rename to: ', expand('%'))
```

It prepopulates the input field with the filename such as `ExampleFile.php`. However I would like to position the cursor just before the `.` as more often than not, users will be renaming the file as opposed to the extension.

However, I cannot figure out a way to move the cursor. Even `<Left><Left><Left>` would suffice if I could get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert special keys in a double quote string with `\<xxx>`. Check the help for `expr-quote`. So just concatenate that to your string:

```
let b:newname = input('Rename to: ', expand('%') . "\<left>\<left>\<left>\<left>")
```