# Select word in input field in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm writing a custom function in Vim which asks the user what they would like to rename the current file to:

`let b:newname = input('Rename to: ', expand('%'))`

It pre-populates the input field with the filename such as ExampleFile.php.

However, is it possible to select only the `ExampleFile` word in the input field so the user could swiftly hit delete and start typing a new name in whilst leaving the extension intact?

I could achieve this easily in `normal` mode using `w` however I'm unsure if this is even possible in an input field.

Comment: Try to use `expand("%:t:r")` rather than `expand('%')`. See `:h expand` for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. What are the benefits of this for other users reading this thread?

Comment: You are welcome. By using `expand("%:t:r")` you can select only the name of the file, and neglect its extension.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, there is no "visual selection" within command mode.

Instead, I  recommend training  your users to  learn other  Vim commands
such  as  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>  which  deletes  the  word  before
cursor.  That, together  your  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43241534/557306)  about moving  the
cursor, should be enough for this case.